# Forking/Multiregistration of same endpoint

Tags: asterisk

**How can we achieve forking/multi-registration of same endpoint in asterisk 11.2 cert1 or greater version ?**

Answer (score 0):

Multiple registrations is supported only by PJSIP stack(starting with Asterisk 12).
To support 5 simultaneous devices you need to make sure that PJSIP user have following line "max_contacts=5".

To dial all devices of extension 1000 you can use following code:

```
Dial(PJSIP/1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I compiled Asterisk 12.8.2 standard version and added user(7000 and 7001) in pjsip.conf. Using Microsip client extension got registered successfully with asterisk but when i initiate call to other pjsip extension asterisk got crashing.

Comment: please help me on the same

Comment: Try Asterisk 13. If you are experiencing crushes with Asterisk, then please open ticket in Jira:
https://issues.asterisk.org/jira

Comment: Asterisk is installed in user defind directory  egg ;/sans/ucc/

Comment: Atlast multiregistration works in Asterisk version 13.5 before this version it is bug in asterisk so Asterisk got crash when dialing PJSIP extension